# multithreading to calculate the min and maximum numbers in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I have written the code to calcuate the minimum and maximum number in a given array using multithreading. The idea is similar to `binarysearch`, I just divide the array into two halves and calculate the min and max of each half and update my min and max fields accordingly.
This could be a stupid example to use for multithreading. but since I thought about this, I want to implement and see how it goes. so far the code SURPRISINGLY works correct. I expected it to not to give correct results, because I am not waiting for first thread to finish and I fire off second thread immediately. This would mean the min and max values must not have updated correctly.
can someone point why this works correctly on multiple runs and any room for improvements.

The code is here

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;



public class MinMax implements Runnable{

    Long min=Long.MAX_VALUE;
    Long max=Long.MIN_VALUE;
    int low;
    int high;
    Long[] arr;

    public  MinMax(int low, int high, Long[] arr){
        this.low = low;
        this.high=high;
        this.arr = arr;

    }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("called run ");
        if (low-high<=2){
            System.out.println("called ");
            List<Long> l = Arrays.asList(arr);
            min=Collections.min(l) < min ? Collections.min(l) : min;
            max=Collections.max(l) > max ? Collections.max(l) : max;
        }
        else {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            int mid = (high+low)/2;
            MinMax left = new MinMax(low,mid,arr);
            MinMax right = new MinMax(mid,high,arr);
            Thread t1 = new Thread(left);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(right);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            Set<Thread> threadset=Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
             for (Thread t : threadset)
                 System.out.println(t.getName());
            try {
                t1.join();
                            t2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
         long[] arr = {3,4,5,1123,567,78,90,5,35434,1,34,56,111,2,56,789,87645,343535};
         Long[] newarr= new Long[arr.length];
         int i = 0;
         for (long temp : arr)
             newarr[i++]=temp;
         MinMax m = new MinMax(0,arr.length,newarr);
         m.run();
         System.out.println(m.min);
         System.out.println(m.max);

    }

}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: should ```t2.run();``` be ```t2.start();``` ? It could be working because the t2 is not running multithreaded.

Comment: if you're spending time on this, might want to look at fork join as well.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery is right, i think your code runs only on the main thread. For debugging purposes it is always a good idea to print out the thread id given by Thread.currentThread()

Comment: @JamesKingsbery: correct me if I am wrong. t1 is spawned into a different thread, for t2, I am handing over to `main` by calling t2.run(), since the `main` thread is going to be sitting idle waiting for t1 and t2 to finish

Comment: @alihaider: I was under the impression that this is fork join, I am joining on t1 thread and t2.run() is implicitly `join` correct (wait for t2 to finish)

Comment: @lwi: I tried including Thread.currentThread and t2.start() instead of t2.run, still I do not see multiple threads being spawned

Comment: @user1988876 - I was referring to the fork join pool - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html

Comment: To start a new thread based on a runnable you have to do the something like new Thread(runnable).start(); See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My remarks for your code - first, `min` and `max` need to be declared `volatile` to make sure their values are updated in time inside the threads.

Then, this comparison is not atomic, you might need to wrap it into `synchronized` block, or think of a `AtomicInteger`'s `compareAndSet` optmization if `synchronized` performance is not satisfying:

```
min=Collections.min(l) < min ? Collections.min(l) : min;
max=Collections.max(l) > max ? Collections.max(l) : max;
```

So the problem could be that both threads calculate their min-value at the same time, but they assign it at different time, so the winner is who's result is being written first.

And as @JamesKingsbery noticed you might need to call `start()` on the second thread.

And may be the last thing, you will probably not get any performance boost in your case, but it's a nice example to study.

Comment: I agree with your point on syncronization. but I do not know if multiple threads are invoked. 'System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());' is not printing any threads at all (see my code edited above)

Comment: You could name your threads: `new Thread("thread1")` and then print `Thread.currentThread().getName()` to be sure. You could also pause execution in your debugger and do a thread dump or just have a look at which threads are where in the debug frame. It's possible in Idea, should be possible in other IDEs too.

Answer (score 4):

Why does it work? First time around `low` is `0` and `high` is around `18`. `low-high<=2` is true and your threaded code is not called. The threaded code doesn't produce any results anyway.

`ForkJoinPool` is designed to handle these sort of things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecursiveAction` class for this. Here I have written program using `RecursiveAction` . Please find the below code. For more info please look http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html

```
package org.kavi.threadexample;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
public class MinMax extends RecursiveAction{

Long min=Long.MAX_VALUE;
Long max=Long.MIN_VALUE;
int low;
int high;
Long[] arr;

public  MinMax(int low, int high, Long[] arr){
    this.low = low;
    this.high=high;
    this.arr = arr;

}

@Override
protected void compute() {
     if (low-high<=2){
         System.out.println("called ");
         List<Long> l = Arrays.asList(arr);
         min=Collections.min(l) < min ? Collections.min(l) : min;
         max=Collections.max(l) > max ? Collections.max(l) : max;
     }
     else {
         int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
         MinMax left = new MinMax(low, mid,arr );
         MinMax right = new MinMax(mid, high, arr);

     }
}


public static void main(String[] args){
     long[] arr = {3,4,5,1123,567,78,90,5,35434,1,34,56,111,2,56,789,87645,343535};
     Long[] newarr= new Long[arr.length];
     int i = 0;
     for (long temp : arr) {
         newarr[i++]=temp;
     }
     MinMax m = new MinMax(0,arr.length,newarr);
     ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
     pool.invoke(m);
     System.out.println(m.min);
     System.out.println(m.max);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version of @KaviK's RecursiveAction example:

(Bugs in KaviK’s version include not actually invoking the recursive tasks, not merging their results and calculating min/max of entire collection at once rather than making any real attempt to subdivide the task)

```
package org.kavi.threadexample;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class MinMax extends RecursiveAction {

    Long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    Long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    int low;
    int high;
    Long[] arr;

    public MinMax(int low, int high, Long[] arr) {
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (high - low <= 2) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, low, high)));
            if (low == high) {
                min = max = arr[low];
            } else {
                min = Math.min(arr[low], arr[low + 1]);
                max = Math.max(arr[low], arr[low + 1]);
            }
        } else {
            // make the left side an exact power of two
            int leftWidth = 1 << (30 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(high - low));
            MinMax left = new MinMax(low, low + leftWidth, arr);
            MinMax right = new MinMax(low + leftWidth, high, arr);
            invokeAll(left, right);
            min = Math.min(left.min, right.min);
            max = Math.max(left.max, right.max);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long[] arr = {3L, 4L, 5L, 1123L, 567L, 78L, 90L, 5L, 35434L, 1L, 34L, 56L, 111L, 2L, 56L, 789L, 87645L, 343535L};
        MinMax m = new MinMax(0, arr.length, arr);
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        pool.invoke(m);
        System.out.println(m.min);
        System.out.println(m.max);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "fixed version? What was (is) wrong with the original one? Please clarify explicitly by making an [edit] to your answer.